# Router is ignored

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Versions:

```
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.19.0",
```

Code:

```
export default function Board() {
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/page/:param1/:param2"><Page/></Route>; 
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  debugger;

  return (
    <>
    <div className="board-row">
      <Square />
      <Square />
      <Square />
    </div>
    <div className="board-row">
      <Square />
      <Square />
      <Square />
    </div>
    <div className="board-row">
      <Square />
      <Square />
      <Square />

    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Another variant is:

```
    <Route exact path="/page/:param1/:param2" component={<Page/>}/>;
```

Then I go to: http://localhost:3000/page/1/2

and stop at the abovementioned debugger.

My expectations are that the Page component will be shown. But the route has been ignored.

What might be the reason for that rule being ignored, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: The "router" is ignored because it is not returned from the function to be rendered to the DOM. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo." Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code, there might be a syntax issue:-

```
export default function Board() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/page/:param1/:param2" element={<Page />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```